# animation is being applied to all list items at once

Tags: angular, angular-animations

I am trying to apply `angular animation` to individual `list item`. On mouseover it gets some color and on mouseleave the color changes.

the list is being generated using `ngFor`.

Problem is when I `hoverover` one `li item`, all of the `li items` get highlighted.

// list component ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-list',
  templateUrl: './list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./list.component.css'],
  animations: [
    trigger('usrSt', [
      state('active', style({ 'background-color': '#cfd8dc' })),
      state('inactive', style({ 'bacckground-color': '#fff' }))
    ])
  ]
})
export class ListComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  public personsList;
  st = 'active';
  @Input() coursestat: string;

  constructor(private getDt: InputDataService) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.personsList = this.getDt.personArr;
    console.log(this.personsList);
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    console.log('destroy list');
  }

  onMouseover() {
    this.st = 'active';
  }
  onMouseleave() {
    this.st = 'inactive';
  }

}
```

// list component html

```
<li class="list-group-item" (mouseover)="onMouseover()" (mouseleave)="onMouseleave()" [@usrSt]="st" [routerLink]= "['/users', i+1, person.name]" *ngFor="let person of (personsList | filter:coursestat:'chosenCourse'); let i = index">
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using ngFor to loop every li and use same **st**

Solution:

Write a separated component for li and use animation for it.

Example

*list.component.html*

```
<app-my-li *ngFor="let person of (personsList | filter:coursestat:'chosenCourse'); let i = index"></app-my-li>
```

*app-my-li.component.ts*

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-li',
  templateUrl: './app-my-li.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app-my-li.component.css'],
  animations: [
    trigger('usrSt', [
      state('active', style({ 'background-color': '#cfd8dc' })),
      state('inactive', style({ 'bacckground-color': '#fff' }))
    ])
  ]
})
export class ListComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  // you might wanna input user person data here

  st = 'active';

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
  }

  onMouseover() {
    this.st = 'active';
  }
  onMouseleave() {
    this.st = 'inactive';
  }
}
```

*app-my-li.component.html*

```
<li  (mouseover)="onMouseover()" (mouseleave)="onMouseleave()" [@usrSt]="st"></li>
```

---

WITHOUT NEW COMPONENT

```
   export class ListComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  public personsList;
  sts = new Array<string>();
  @Input() coursestat: string;

  constructor(private getDt: InputDataService) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.personsList = this.getDt.personArr;

    // this.sts = Array.from(this.personalList, _ => 'active');
    this.personalList.forEach(_ => this.sts.push('active'));

    console.log(this.personsList);
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    console.log('destroy list');
  }

  onMouseover(i: number) {
    this.sts[i] = 'active';
  }
  onMouseleave(i: number) {
    this.sts[i] = 'inactive';
  }

}

<li class="list-group-item" (mouseover)="onMouseover(i)" (mouseleave)="onMouseleave(i)" [@usrSt]="sts[i]" [routerLink]= "['/users', i+1, person.name]" *ngFor="let person of (personsList | filter:coursestat:'chosenCourse'); let i = index">
```

Comment: i didnt understand what you are saying. can you explain it in some more detail please

Comment: you are creating a bunch of <li> that share a same variable 'st', thats the reason you have them all animate at same time. create individual component to hold individual state for each li will make it works

Comment: but thats couldnt be correct solution. how can we avoid using ngfor if we want to use animation

Comment: Since you would like to animate a list of element, you need an array to hold their states.

Comment: in your example the index `i` is not set dynamically. how do you set that

Comment: i comes from ngFor loop index, each sts[i] is individual state holder for list

Comment: i is not bound to any property in the component

Comment: isnt there any easier solution like just getting the index and based on index set the value of the `st`